# Why does MPI_Barrier cause a segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi, barrier

I have reduced my program to the following example:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run the code, and get the following result:

```
My-MacBook-Pro-2:xCode_TrapSim user$ mpicxx -g -O0 -Wall barrierTest.cpp -o barrierTestExec
My-MacBook-Pro-2:xCode_TrapSim user$ mpiexec -n 2 ./barrierTestExec

==================================================================================    =
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 21633 RUNNING AT My-MacBook-Pro-2.local
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault: 11 (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

If I comment out the MPI_Barrier, or run the program on only one node, the code runs fine. I am using the following compilers:

```
My-MacBook-Pro-2:xCode_TrapSim user$ mpiexec --version
HYDRA build details:
Version:                                 3.2
Release Date:                            Wed Nov 11 22:06:48 CST 2015
CC:                              clang    
CXX:                             clang++    
F77:                             /usr/local/bin/gfortran   
F90:                             /usr/local/bin/gfortran   
Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mpich/3.2_1' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/mpich/3.2_1/share/man' 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++' 'FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran' 'F77=/usr/local/bin/gfortran' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CFLAGS= -O2' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBS=-lpthread ' 'CPPFLAGS= -I/private/tmp/mpich-20160606-48824-1qsaqn8/mpich-3.2/src/mpl/include -I/private/tmp/mpich-20160606-48824-1qsaqn8/mpich-3.2/src/mpl/include -I/private/tmp/mpich-20160606-48824-1qsaqn8/mpich-3.2/src/openpa/src -I/private/tmp/mpich-20160606-48824-1qsaqn8/mpich-3.2/src/openpa/src -D_REENTRANT -I/private/tmp/mpich-20160606-48824-1qsaqn8/mpich-3.2/src/mpi/romio/include'
Process Manager:                         pmi
Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
Topology libraries available:            hwloc
Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
Checkpointing libraries available:       
Demux engines available:                 poll select


My-MacBook-Pro-2:xCode_TrapSim user$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

This seems like it should be a trivial problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. Why would MPI_Barrier cause this simple code to seg fault?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code runs without crashing here.

Comment: I'm not surprised, it's an almost trivial example of MPI, and yet whatever compiler combo I have or something is just not cooperating. I'm just kind of hoping someone might have seen this before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your question is well asked, it is still difficult to reproduce thus understand your issue. The likely answer is *there is something wrong with your MPI installation*, but that's not too helpful. Could you maybe add some details on how you installed MPI? Ultimately a bug report to the package provider (assuming it is from a repository) might be more promising.

Answer (score 0):

It is supper hard to decide what is wrong with your installation. However, if you can use any of the MPI flavors, maybe you can try this one:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3492

All I can say, it works with Open MPI

```
~/opt/usr/local/bin/mpicxx -g -O0 -Wall barrierTestExec.cpp -o barrierTestExec
~/opt/usr/local/bin/mpiexec -n 2 ./barrierTestExec
```

and no exception in my case. It really seems to be environment specific.